# How to get current button`id in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Let's suppose I have this this simple button:

```
{
   xtype :'button',
   text :'button',
   id:'address'+counter.no,
   handler : function() {}
}
```

How can I get access to the current button and get access to its properties such as name, id, etc?

I'm aware of `Ext.getCmp('compid')` but I need to get access to CURRENT button, and I don't know its `id`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean inside the handler function?

See [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-handler) at description for `handler`.
As first parameter `this` button object is passed, so you could do the following:

```
{
   xtype :'button',
   text :'button',
   id:'address'+counter.no,
   handler : function(thisButton, eventObject) {
       //Do something with thisButton like:
       alert(thisButton.getId());
   }
}
```